# Button dissapear when value reaches 0 JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

This my code:

```
$('.upgrade-strength').on('click', function () {
    var strCount = $('#strId');
    var points = $('#points');
    var userId = $(this).attr('id');
    strCount.html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 }); 
    points.html(function(i, val) { 

    if(val*1>0){
         return val*1-1;
     }else{
        document.getElementById("strBtn").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("dexBtn").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("vitBtn").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("intBtn").innerHTML = "";
     }

});

    $.ajax("/upgrade-strength/"+userId,
    {

    });     
});
```

`<p>Available points: <strong><span id="points">{{Auth::user()->points}}</span></strong></p>`

When I clicking the button the counter goes down till 0 and then button dissapears. But what happens more is, when the 
`points.html(function(i, val)` reaches zero the button did not dissapear. You have to click one more time tu buttons dissapear. How to solve this ?

Comment: Please provide the entire code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work:

```
strCount.html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 }); 
    points.html(function(i, val) { 

    if(val*1>0){
         val = val*1-1;
         if(val == 0){
             document.getElementById("strBtn").innerHTML = "";
             document.getElementById("dexBtn").innerHTML = "";
             document.getElementById("vitBtn").innerHTML = "";
             document.getElementById("intBtn").innerHTML = "";
         }
         return val;
     }else{
        document.getElementById("strBtn").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("dexBtn").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("vitBtn").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("intBtn").innerHTML = "";
     }
```

Comment: "Try this [code]" answers are bad. You haven't explained what you've changed, why you've changed it, and how this solves the problem. As it is, you're violating DRY pretty hard.

Answer (score 0):

When `val` is `1`, look at your code, and see what it's doing:

- `if(val*1>0)` - I don't know why you keep using `*1` but never mind that. `1 > 0` is true, so we're in the `if` block.
- `return val*1-1;` - again, what's the deal with `*1`? Anyway, this returns `0`.
- The `else` block *is not run*.

The next time you click, `if(val*1>0)` is false so the `else` gets run, hiding the buttons.

Instead you should do something like:

- If the value is `1`, hide the buttons
- Either way, `return val-1;`